# How to make changes on live wordpress website which has woocommerce data and orders?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to make changes to live WordPress websites like posts and pages.I used the woocommerce plugin on my website for purchasing products. How can I make website changes without affecting the customers? How can I know the changes in backend SQL file if I make the changes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It can be done basically in two ways:

1) Keep the website in maintenance mode and make the changes accordingly. There are many plugins out there. Ex. Wp Maintenance mode

2) You can update the website, it being live directly for ex. by editing the product details directly or you can edit any data whatever you wish to change.

After making the changes you will see the update changes going live. You don't need to goto mysql shell for this.

Hope this might help.

Answer (score 1):

To edit a post that already exists on your site, go to Posts > All Posts in your WordPress dashboard. Click on the title of the post you want to edit in the list provided. If your list spans several pages, you can click through each page or enter your post’s title in the search box.

If you’re changing the post content, click on the post’s title to view the edit page. Make your changes to the post as needed. Once you’re finished, click the Update button to save your edited post.

[image]

The same goes with the page editing.

**This will not effect to your Order or Products**